# Framerate lag spikes from network requests on main thread

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, task

I'm currently working on a project to power NPC conversations using OpenAI's GPT3. Each NPC sends a POST request to my server when it's their time to speak in a conversation, which returns an audio file that the NPC plays through its local AudioSource.

Video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pygM6yDE9hI

One issue that I'm experiencing is jitter and short periods of lag.

[image]

I'm a novice when it comes to Unity, but based on the profiler I believe the culprits are the Coroutines handling the network requests.

Below is my code for this functionality:

```
     // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     int index = -1;
     if (conversation != null)
     {
         if (!conversation.processing)
         {
             if (conversation.currentSpeaker.Equals(this.id))
             {
                 Debug.Log(this.id + " getting response");
                 conversation.processing = true;
                 StartCoroutine(getResponse(conversation));
             }
         }
     }
     else if (Datastore.Instance.id2conversation.TryGetValue(id, out index))
     {
         conversation = Datastore.Instance.conversations[index];
     }
 }

 IEnumerator getResponse(Conversation conversation)
 {
     WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
     form.AddField("id", this.id);
     var www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://" + Datastore.Instance.host + ":3000/generate", form);

     yield return www.SendWebRequest();

     if (interrupted) yield break;

     if (www.isNetworkError)
     {
         Debug.Log(www.error);
     }
     else
     {
         if (www.GetResponseHeaders().Count > 0)
         {
             var jsonData = JSON.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text);

             string stringData = jsonData["audioContent"]["data"].ToString();
             byte[] rawdata = AudioHelpers.ConvertToByteStream(stringData);

             AudioClip clip = AudioHelpers.ConvertToAudioClip(rawdata);

             this.audioSource.clip = clip;
             this.audioSource.Play();

             this.animator.SetBool(this.talkingBoolHash, true);

             Debug.Log("Response Recieved");

             yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);

             if (interrupted) yield break;

             this.conversation.currentSpeaker = jsonData["nextSpeaker"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
             this.conversation.processing = false;
             this.animator.SetBool(this.talkingBoolHash, false);
         }
     }
 }
```

How can I improve the performance of this code to remove the periods of decreased framerate?

Is it possible to move this code to another thread via Unity Jobs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Deep Profiler:
[image: Deep Profiler View]

Implemented threading for JSON parsing. New code:

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int index = -1;
        if (conversation != null)
        {
            if (!conversation.processing)
            {
                if (conversation.currentSpeaker.Equals(this.id))
                {
                    Debug.Log(this.id + " getting response");
                    conversation.processing = true;
                    StartCoroutine(getResponse(conversation));
                }
            }
        }
        else if (Datastore.Instance.id2conversation.TryGetValue(id, out index))
        {
            conversation = Datastore.Instance.conversations[index];
        }

    }

    Task<(byte[], string)> ParseAudioData(string rawJson)
    {
        try
        {
            return Task.Run(() => {
                var jsonData = JSON.Parse(rawJson);
                string stringData = jsonData["audioContent"]["data"].ToString();
                byte[] rawdata = AudioHelpers.ConvertToByteStream(stringData);
                string nextSpeaker = jsonData["nextSpeaker"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                return Task.FromResult((rawdata, nextSpeaker));
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogException(e);
        throw;
    }
}

    IEnumerator getResponse(Conversation conversation)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("id", this.id);

        var www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://" + Datastore.Instance.host + ":3000/generate", form);

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (interrupted) yield break;

        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            if (www.GetResponseHeaders().Count > 0)
            {
                Task<(byte[], string)> t = ParseAudioData(www.downloadHandler.text);

                yield return t;

                AudioClip clip = AudioHelpers.ConvertToAudioClip(t.Result.Item1);

                this.audioSource.clip = clip;
                this.audioSource.Play();

                this.animator.SetBool(this.talkingBoolHash, true);

                Debug.Log("Response Recieved");

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);

                if (interrupted) yield break;

                this.conversation.currentSpeaker = t.Result.Item2;
                this.conversation.processing = false;
                this.animator.SetBool(this.talkingBoolHash, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Final Edit: Got it working with help from the answer below!

My final code:

```
Task<JSONNode> ParseJsonData(string rawJson)
{
    try
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            JSONNode jsonData = JSON.Parse(rawJson);
            return jsonData;
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogException(e);
        throw;
    }
}

Task<(byte[], string)> ParseAudioData(JSONNode jsonData)
{
    try
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            string stringData = jsonData["audioContent"]["data"].ToString();
            byte[] rawdata = AudioHelpers.ConvertToByteStream(stringData);
            string nextSpeaker = jsonData["nextSpeaker"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
            return (rawdata, nextSpeaker);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogException(e);
        throw;
    }
}
IEnumerator PlayDialog(AudioClip clip, string nextSpeaker)
{
    this.audioSource.clip = clip;
    this.audioSource.Play();
    this.animator.SetBool(this.talkingBoolHash, true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);

    if (interrupted) yield break;

    this.conversation.currentSpeaker = nextSpeaker;
    this.conversation.processing = false;
    this.animator.SetBool(this.talkingBoolHash, false);
}

IEnumerator getResponse(Conversation conversation)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("id", this.id);
    var www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://" + Datastore.Instance.host + ":3000/generate", form);

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (interrupted) yield break;

    if (www.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        if (www.GetResponseHeaders().Count > 0)
        {
            ParseJsonData(www.downloadHandler.text).ContinueWith((jsonData) => {
                ParseAudioData(jsonData.Result).ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    // https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher
                    UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(() =>
                    {
                        AudioClip clip = AudioHelpers.ConvertToAudioClip(t.Result.Item1);
                        StartCoroutine(PlayDialog(clip, t.Result.Item2));
                        Debug.Log("Response Recieved");
                    });
                });
            });
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not understanding `return Task.FromResult`.  That method should usually be avoided for reasons I won't get into.  Did you try using the answer below?  If yes, what were the problems?  This is a bit hard to follow in my head but you don't want to block on the Task running in the background.

Comment: @Zer0 I wasn't able to directly copy and paste the answer below because the code within the ContinueWith didn't have rawdata variable in scope. Additionally, when I did get it working through some minor tweaks, nothing happened, which I'm naively assuming is because you're not allowed to call Unity API in other threads.


Still very inexperienced with C# syntax. What should be used instead of Task.FromResult?

Comment: Try `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` as a parameter to `ContinueWith` to get that to run back on the main thread.  I'm not familiar with Unity, so someone can correct me if that doesn't work.  If not, could try `async await` instead?

Comment: @Zer0 do you have any recommendations on TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()?
I haven't seen it before and don't quite understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that probably the lag spikes are coming from the JSON parsing and transforming it into an AudioClip. You can probably do this on a different thread:

```cs
Task<byte[]> ParseJsonData (string rawJson)
{
    try
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            jsonData = JSON.Parse(rawJson);
            string stringData = jsonData["audioContent"]["data"].ToString();
            return AudioHelpers.ConvertToByteStream(stringData);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogException(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```cs
IEnumerator getResponse(Conversation conversation)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("id", this.id);
    var www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://" + Datastore.Instance.host + ":3000/generate", form);

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (interrupted) yield break;

    if (www.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        if (www.GetResponseHeaders().Count > 0)
        {
            ParseJsonData(rawJson)
                .ContinueWith(ParseAudioData);
            ParseAudioData(www.downloadHandler.text).ContinueWith((rawData) =>
            {
                // https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher
                UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance.Enqueue(() =>
                {
                    AudioClip clip = AudioHelpers.ConvertToAudioClip(rawData);
                    StartCoroutine(PlayDialog(clip));
                    Debug.Log("Response Recieved");
                });
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator PlayDialog (AudioClip clip)
{
    this.audioSource.clip = clip;
    this.audioSource.Play();
    this.animator.SetBool(this.talkingBoolHash, true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);
    if (interrupted) yield break;
    this.conversation.currentSpeaker = jsonData["nextSpeaker"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
    this.conversation.processing = false;
    this.animator.SetBool(this.talkingBoolHash, false);
}
```

This will send the operations to a new thread and continue with your code when the operations end. If the lag spikes are coming from parsing the json this should help it. Take care when running code from other threads, since you cannot access most of Unity functionality and it's all async.

Edit: Included some utils for running code on the MainThread, because as others pointed out, this wouldn't work without fiddling with synchronization context.

Also, I'd recommend for you to try to separate your methods with single responsibilities. As of now your coroutine is downloading stuff, parsing it, playing audio and updating the dialog status. This is quite a lot a for a single function.

Your JSON should also be a structured class, it makes little sense to parse it and still access stuff by its string hash.

If this still doesn't solve your issue, you might need to dive a bit deeper into the profiler and check exactly what is causing it spend so much time in the main thread.

Comment: I'd suggest `throw;` instead of `throw e;` so you don't mess up the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you! Currently working on implementing this. How does ContinueWith work? Where does the code below it get access to the rawdata variable?

Comment: `ContinueWith` is something that runs after a `Task` completes in one fashion or another.   You can specify when it should run that (success, error, etc...).  It's basically how `async await` works under the covers.

Comment: Will the Unity API methods be able to be called from within the ContinueWith()?

Comment: @Zer0 Made an edit to include my new code. I think it's running faster but there are still noticeable spikes and was wondering if I implemented something incorrectly. To my understanding, Unity API can't be accessed from other threads which is why I wrote the updated code the way I did. How can I improve it?

Comment: Hey sorry, didn't pay much attention to the code I wrote before. I've update it. Thanks for the suggestions @Zer0.

Comment: @HarrisR I've check your updated profiler and the Task seems to be running in the MainThread. I'm not exactly sure that you can simply await a Task like that inside a coroutine, that might be the problem.